# Comment traduire l'expression anglaise “When/If shit hits the fan, [conséquences…]”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, argot

Même si son sens est assez clair, j'ai souvent du mal à rendre en français l'équivalent de cette expression anglaise, qu'on ne rencontre qu'à l'oral ou dans des échanges écrits très informels, sur le web notamment.

Avez-vous des propositions meilleures que les variantes (comme ci-dessous) que j'utilise parfois ?

> When shit hits the fan, you'll see them all run for cover.
>
> *Quand ça va merder, tu les verras tous courir aux abris.*

---

Edit suite à la remarque (pertinente) de Papa Poule à propos de la forme autour de l'expression en elle-même : la partie qui m'intéresse est le coeur de l'expression, *shit hits the fan*, n'hésitez pas à la placer dans un autre contexte si ça vous semble plus clair.

Comment: Et sa version pré-électricité : *“When shit hits the Archimedes screw”*.

Comment: "Partir en couille" peut-être?

Comment: Peut-on avoir plus de contexte ?

Comment: @iKiWiXz Plus de contexte ? En plus d'une recherche google sur 'shit hits the fan' qui reste très informative, tu peux trouver l'expression dans tous les différents dictionnaires urban/slang (un exemple [ici](http://fr.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit+hit+the+fan)) qui pullulent sur le web, des paroles de [chanson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5HB-JXecjk) et mêmes certaines intéressantes [questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21860/whats-the-etymology-of-when-the-sht-hits-the-fan).

Comment: The verb is "courir", not "courrir".

Comment: @RomainVALERI J'envisageais juste de donner une expression peut-être plus adaptée. Vous devez savoir que l'on ne peut pas traduire l'anglais en français mot par mot (ni expression par expression) sans perdre une partie aussi infime soit-elle du sens.

Comment: @RobertGreen c'est corrigé, merci ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En français, on dit parfois "ça va chier dans le ventilo". Une référence culturelle de haut niveau le confirme: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf-4ie6jj7g

Je n'ai jamais entendu les expressions proposées par Bazin et Bernard Massé, et elles ne me paraissent pas naturelles. La traduction proposée dans la question me paraît correcte, même si la raison pour laquelle ils courent s'abriter devient moins évidente.

Pour une traduction littérale, je proposerais: "Quand ça chiera dans le ventilo, ils se mettront tous à couvert". Mais l'expression "chier dans le ventilo" s'emploie surtout sous la forme "ça va chier dans le ventilo". Donc cette traduction littérale sonne encore un peu artificielle.

Comment: +1 Nice! "Ca va chier dans le ventilo" certainly captures the entire visual image, both coming and going! For another high-level confirmation, [here's a video clip (at 3:16)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xhb5chrJ9U) of Muriel Robin using it in her sketch "LA REUNION DE CHANTIER" and in [its textual form here (lines 27-28 on full-size screen).](http://www.atatheatre.com/saynetes3/Robin1.htm)

Answer (score 7):

Putting "when" in front of "the shit hits the fan" makes it tougher. 
For example, "The shit will surely hit the fan WHEN my wife gets home" would be fairly easy: "[Ca va vraiment chier [des bulles]](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/%C3%A7a%20va%20chier%20des%20bulles) QUAND ma femme rentre."

I'm not sure, however, if "ça va chier..." works as well AFTER "quand" or if it would even capture the desired meaning.

Therefore, AFTER the "quand," I'd propose:

> [Quand ça va leur péter dans la figure/gueule](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/%C3%A7a%20va%20nous%20peter%20dans%20la%20figure), tu les verras tous courir aux
>   abris.

Comment: +1 pour *Ca va chier des bulles* auquel je n'avais pas pensé.

Answer (score 3):

« *The shit hit the fan* » c'est au moins très informel sinon vulgaire vu l'emploi de [*shit*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-french/shit).<sup>1</sup> Le [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-french/the-shit-hit-the-fan) rend par:

> ça a chié (v. inf)

Une réponse s'appuie déjà sur ce verbe, mais seul c'est plus fort à mon avis, et plus naturel que « merder ». Simplement utiliser « quand ça chie » au présent de l'indicatif avec une construction en complément, dans le sens de quand les choses *se gâtent* ou *[tournent](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tourner) mal/[au vinaigre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vinaigre)/pas rond* - c'est selon. Mais il s'agit du *summum* dramatique,  d'un moment cathartique en soi: il y a précipitation d'un scénario désastreux, ça [*saute*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sauter), parfois un monde s'écroule autour. Ça se produit quand par exemple une information, qu'on ne veut divulguer, s'évente, est révélée, et qu'il y a une réaction, haute en couleur et souvent négative qui suit, ou généralement quand la situation est dramatique et qu'il y a des conséquences navrantes qui changent la donne; on est salement  « éclaboussé », ce que d'aucuns tentent d'éviter. *The shit hit the fan*, tout comme le *ça a chié*, c'est très elliptique<sup>1.5</sup>.

---

On peut aussi s'intéresser au deuxième segment en utilisant l'analogie maritime: *les [rats](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rats) quittent le navire*; quand il coule, que l'eau monte, quand il s'enflamme etc. mais c'est davantage un instinct qu'une fuite.<sup>2</sup> Similaire, au futur:

> Tu verras: dès que/lorsque/quand ça va chier, ils vont [déguerpir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9guerpir)/se sauver/[foutre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foutre) le
>   camp/[décamper](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9camper)/aller se cacher/se défiler.

Bien justement c'est que normalement c'est davantage [*take cover*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Take+Cover)([Q&A](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/41102)), [*run for it*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+for+it) ou [*try to cover one's ass*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cover+ass) qui sont les idiomes de choix, me semble-t-il, plutôt que *run for cover*.  Il semble que la source en anglais ait tenté d'exprimer les trois??

---

<sub>1. Voir [*TFD*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+shit+hits+the+fan)(rude/taboo vs. slang pour [*hits the fan*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hits+the+fan)), *AHD* ([vulgar slang](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shit) vs. [slang](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hit%20the%20fan)), [*Dictionary.com*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fan). Une [discussion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:when_the_shit_hits_the_fan) intéressante sur l'[origine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_the_shit_hits_the_fan), dans le sens de la [Q&A](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21860/) sur *ELU* présentée en commentaire, possiblement *shit hit de fan* avant *hit the fan*, mais pas dans la [littérature](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shit%20hit%20the%20fan%2Chit%20the%20fan&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshit%20hit%20the%20fan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chit%20the%20fan%3B%2Cc0)(le corpus de Google Books), où c'est l'inverse. On voit aussi que *hit the fan* est peut-être aussi possible dans le sens d'[explosion](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=PkYyT_G4MrTY4QSWvv3AAQ&id=X8d8AAAAIAAJ&dq=%22hit%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hits%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hitting%20the%20fan%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22hit%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hits%20the%20fan%22%20OR%20%22hitting%20the%20fan%22).</sub>

<sub>1.5 Une **parodie** d'article([ici](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Shit_Hits_The_Fan)) sur le sujet.</sub>

<sub>2. "*Lors d'une catastrophe, c'est le sauve-qui-peut!*"(la débandade), "*Lors d'une tempête, on voit les gens rechercher un abri/tenter de s'abriter.*"(la conséquence logique). Ça illustre à mon avis comment la deuxième partie vient s'appuyer sur la première, sur cet évènement, et autoriser plein de rendus différents et plus élaborés que si on a seulement la première partie, plus générique.</sub>

Comment: +1 for the entire analysis, but especially for discussing the different choices of verb tenses to use. Although I used the "futur proche" in my answer, I now suspect that the present would have been a better (and perhaps the only) choice.

Answer (score 1):

«Partir en vrille»

I have heard that expression and used it myself at times. @Bart' comment is also quite frequent, in even less formal settings!

Comment: Oui, c'est vrai que ça correspond bien, mais alors quand c'est *[quelque chose/la situation] qui part en vrille/en couille/en sucette* plutôt que quand le sujet est [quelqu'un].

Answer (score 0):

Je proposerais: "Quand l'autocuiseur va exploser...". Un autocuiseur est un "pressure cooker" en anglais. Je crois qu'on pourrait même dire: "Quand la marmite va exploser...". Évidemment, ce qu'il y a dans la marmite n'est pas nécessairement la même chose que ce qui frappe le ventilateur, mais on comprend qu'il va y en avoir partout.

Answer (score 0):

When shit hits the fan, you'll see them all run for cover:

Quand le presse-purée atteindra la merde, tu les verras tous se planquer.

It seems to me that the translation should capture the strong image of flying shit.

Answer (score 0):

When the shit hits the fan : quand ça va se mettre à merder...
'Partir en couilles', 'chier dans le ventilo' sont pas mal non plus.